# Infimum of random variables is a random variable. Clarification of proof.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, supremum-and-infimum

Let $(\Omega, {\cal A}, {\Bbb P})$ be the probability space. If $X_n$ are random variables then for all $ \{X_n < a\}\in {\cal A}$ and for all $n \in \Bbb N$ and $a \in \Bbb R$,

$$\left\{\inf_n X_n < a\right\} = \bigcup_n \left\{ X_n < a \right\} \in {\cal A}$$

This statement was written in a proof for infimum $X_n$ being a random variable. Can someone please explain why $\left\{\inf\limits_n X_n < a\right\}$ is equal to the union over the set $\{X_n < a\}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's helpful to read the union as "there's some $n$ such that". So the equality you're interested in translates in English to "$\inf X_n < a$ if and only if there's some $n$ such that $X_n < a$."

But that follows easily from the definition of $\inf$. Indeed, suppose $\inf X_n < a$. Since for all $\epsilon > 0$ there's some $n$ such that $X_n - \inf_n X_n < \epsilon$, it follows (with $\epsilon = (a - \inf_n X_n)/2$, for example) that there's some $n$ such that $X_n < a$. Conversely, if there's some $n$ such that $X_n < a$, then clearly $\inf_n X_n < a$ since the $\inf$ is a lower bound.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I forgot you can look at the union in that sense.